# Projection in query

Tags: solr, lucene, liferay, liferay-6

In solr, there is parameter "fl", which provides projection in query. How can I achieve same feature in liferay?

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

*fl* is not a projection in a SOLR query, it simply selects the result fields.

First of all: Liferay is using Lucene as search engine - not SOLR.

If "*in liferay*" means "*in the UI*": You can't select the result fields in the UI. The results are objects from the database that were filtered by Lucene (for some of the search forms and some configurations the result is retrieved even without Lucene directly from the database using SQL).

If "*in liferay*" means "*in the API*": You can select the result fields, if you access the Lucene indexer in low level (the `...ServiceUtil.search` methods won't help) and use a `FieldSelector`:

```java
IndexSearcher indexSearcher = LuceneHelperUtil.getIndexSearcher(companyId);
IndexReader indexReader = indexSearcher.getIndexReader();

FieldSelector fieldSelector = new FieldSelector() {
    public FieldSelectorResult accept(String fieldName) {
        // Only return "my-field"
        if ("my-field".equals(fieldName)) {
            return FieldSelectorResult.LOAD_AND_BREAK;
        }
        return FieldSelectorResult.NO_LOAD;
    }
};

TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.query(luceneQuery, maxDocuments);

// Retrieve only the selected fields for the hits
List<Document> results = new ArrayList<Document>();
for (int i = 0; i < topDocs.scoreDocs.length; i++) {
     results.add(indexReader.document(topDocs.scoreDocs[i].doc, fieldSelector));
}
```

You can use any of the other query methods as well.
Have a look at `com.liferay.portal.search.lucene.LuceneIndexSearcher` to find out how to build your query correctly.